# Word wrap in FusionCharts Free data labels

Tags: fusioncharts

I use [FusionCharts Free](http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/) to plot some column charts.  Some of the data labels (the texts under each column on the *x*-axis) are long, and end up overlapping with the labels of other columns.  Is it possible to make the text wrap?

(I know it is possible to [rotate](http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/docs/Contents/ChartSS/XML_Column2D.html) labels, but that is not an option for me because it strips out any non-ASCII characters.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping of the *x*-axis label is not available in FusionCharts Free.  It *is*, however, available in the commercial product [FusionCharts 3](http://www.fusioncharts.com/).

Source: [answer from customer support](http://www.fusioncharts.com/forum/Topic19198-40-1.aspx#bm19226)

Answer (score 3):

You could try using the '&#10;' character as a new line break for this. Just a common workaround for this though. You would have to place it in-between the Label, from where you would like it to 'wrap'.

Hope this helps someone. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use {br}.

Here is the link below:

http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/usage-guide/chart-guide/heat-map-chart/configuring-labels-and-tool-tips.html

Comment: The link is for FusionCharts Flex. Does `{br}` work for FusionCharts Free also?

Answer (score 0):

Also, FusionCharts Free is an open source product. So feel free to modify the source code in any way which suits you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

if need above result and you working on fusion chart trial version

you need to bind label `'Oct<br>2014'` using 
 tage

and it's working me..